# Remove observations if variable has NA in read.csv step in R

Tags: r, csv

I am importing a csv file in R. If data are missing for a specific `variable`, I need to delete that observation. This is quite simple in two steps:

```r
#Example code
data<-read.csv('filepath/file.csv', header=TRUE, na.strings=c(""))
data<-data[!is.na(data$variable),]
```

Is there a way to do this in a single step (the read.csv step)? I could not find anything relating to omission for specific variable in this regard after searching.

Unfortunately, since this involves importing a file, I am not sure how to make a reproducible example (I searched extensively to try!)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to do this?

Comment: I usually pipe read.csv to dplyr to make all necessary transformation,  in your case it would be just filter(!is.na(variable). If you need an example, let me know.

Comment: Thank you Pawel, I will try pipping it through dpylr! Great idea, all my other code is in base R so I wasn't thinking about packages. And @jyr - yes I have prepared the code to be copied and pasted by peer reviewers and ran at once; there is a bizarre quirk where this step results in issues. I can only imagine the reason is a technical install reason but figured it would be easier to code around the issue than ask others to upend their install. Thanks again to you both!

Comment: I cannot think why would this cause any kind of issue. Maybe you can save the file without the NA and send it instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** If you are asking how to do this in one line of code use `subset` like this:

```
subset(read.csv('filepath/file.csv', na.strings = ""), !is.na(variable))
```

**2)** Another possibility is the following.  You might need additional arguments but since we don't have the file you will need to determine that yourself.  This reads the file into an sqlite database which it creates on the fly and then after processing reads the result into R.  The NA rows are never read into R.

```
library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql('filepath/file.csv', "select * from file where variable is not null")
```